# Does coffee stain enamel?

Tags: ground-coffee

I would like to know if ground-coffee stains the enamel of our teeth. If so, how long and how frequent would its exposure to coffee be in order to acquire a taint or colouring? It is possible too that only additives to the coffee result in an affect to the enamel of our teeth.

Answer (score 3):

Yes...tea and wine too.  Hydrogen peroxide and baking soda can remove coffee stains from enamel.  Organic bits of the plants stain enamel over time.

Comment: Welcome! Can you also address the second part of the question - how quickly does the staining happen - if you have the knowledge? You can always [edit] your own posts, there’s a little link under your post for that. As for all new users, let me point you to the [tour] and our [help], which give an introduction to how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a few cups a day of black coffee will stain your teeth noticeably over a month or two (personal experience). It's easy to fix with a whitening toothpaste. You don't need one containing bleach; the one I use contains titanium dioxide. It got rid of the staining in a few days.

Comment: Are you sure that actually whitens the teeth? According to this [article](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-remove-toothpaste-stains-2146960) it's merely used to make the paste look whiter, it doesn't make the teeth whiter.